# Android Application with MVC model

Tags: android

I'm doing an application price comparison android, I block at level design (MVC model)
help me with a tutorial class diagram with MVC

Answer (score 0):

In the android, I think the Adapter is designed in MVC model wonderfully, especially the SampleCursorAdapter is good one.  .http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html.

it connect with the database cursor(which is model), and list view(which is view).
when the cursor data changed, it notified the view, and it make the strategy to how put the data in the view. 
when the view change the database, it also notified the adapter to reload the data, and refresh the view itself.

Hope this help you.